# Does SonarLint send codes to sonar server?

Tags: sonarlint

### Does sonarLint send codes to sonar server ?

---

I am a user of sonarLint.
I just worried about if sonarLint send my codes to sonar server, i will be problems.

So I just want to know that sonarList send codes to sonar server ?

Answer (score 4):

The aim of SonarLint is to run local analyses. The connected experience makes you able to grab configuration and plugins updates from SonarQube server but SonarLint analyses are not pushed from the IDE to SonarQube server.

Comment: Thanks to you. I can find answer to my question.

Comment: @user3555888: You should accept Jean-Denis Coffre's answer then! :)